# Não grava dados com MySql

Tags: php, javascript

Boas galera, estou com a seguinte complicação, cada doente tem um chamado "PII" e e esse mesmo "PII" tem várias dados. O problema é ao preencher o PII ao clicar em gravar ele simplesmente me limpa todos os dados em vez de armazenar na base de dados.

O excerto inicial do php a fazer ligação com o MySql:

```
    <?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0)
    {   
header('location:index.php');
}
else{
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$avinicial=$_POST['AvInicial'];
$meta=$_POST['Meta'];
$avintercalar=$_POST['AvIntercalar'];
$avfinal=$_POST['AvFinal'];
$datainicio=$_POST['DataInicio'];
$datafim=$_POST['DataFim'];
$resultadouni=$_POST['ResultadoUni'];
$avalexp=$_POST['AvalExpec'];
$concretizaobj=$_POST['ConcretizaObj'];
$objdefinidos=$_POST['ObjDefinidos'];
$objatingidos=$_POST['ObjAtingidos'];
$totalalcancados=$_POST['TotalAlcancados'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblobjetivos(AvInicial, Meta, AvIntercalar, AvFinal, DataInicio, DataFim, ResultadoUni, AvalExpec, ConcretizaObj, ObjDefinidos, ObjAtingidos, TotalAlcancados) VALUES(:avinicial, :meta, :avintercalar, :avfinal, :datainicio, :datafim, :resultadouni, :avalexp, :concretizaobj, :objdefinidos, :objatingidos, :totalalcancados)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':avinicial', $avinicial, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':meta', $meta, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':avintercalar', $avintercalar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':avfinal', $avfinal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':datainicio', $datainicio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':datafim', $datafim, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':resultadouni', $resultadouni, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':avalexp', $avalexp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':concretizaobj', $concretizaobj, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':objdefinidos', $objdefinidos, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':objatingidos', $objatingidos, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':totalalcancados', $totalalcancados, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
$query->execute();

    if ($lastInsertId) {
        $msg = "PII Adicionado com Sucesso";
    } else {
        $error = "Confirme se preencheu tudo corretamente!";
    }
}?>
```

[image: Tabela que deveria armazenar os valores do PII]
[image: Tabela dos doentes]

Comment: Precisa ser mais claro na pergunta. Limpa como? Limpa onde ou o quê exatamente?

Comment: Quando eu clico para os dados do formulário serem armazenados na base de dados desaparece tudo o que preenchi no formulário e na base de dados não aparece valor nenhum.

Comment: @sam o problema é que cada doente pode ter até 12 objetivos, ou seja são 12 vezes cada valor da tabela objetivos entende? como posso fazer isto armazenar direito na base de dados? deverei criar mais alguma tabela?

Comment: @Bacco se já o tinha dito em outra questão porque tem de dizer novamente? Basta uma vez meu caro. Mas obrigado pelo tempo da sua vida que perdeu para me tentar "ajudar" ! cumprimentos!

Answer (score -1):

Não é uma solução mas uma dica: no arquivo de conexão (provavelmente /include/config.php), configure o PDO para disparar exceções. Nestas exceções irão constar informações importantes, como o motivo de os dados não estarem sendo persistidos no banco. Por exemplo, se no banco uma coluna é NOT NULL e você estiver tentando adicionar um valor nulo, irá disparar uma exceção com a mensagem.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.error-handling.php

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O -1 não é meu, e nem sei ao certo o motivo de quem votou negativo, mas eu acho interessante nesses casos talvez deixar um comentário em vez de resposta. Entendo que como tem código, seria um pouco mais complicado, mas só estou comentando pq como vejo que vc está procurando responder várias questões, e a sua conta é nova, talvez seja legal atentar pra esses detalhes que podem causar uma certa rejeição nas respostas. Como você já tem pontos suficientes, pode frequentar o [chat da rede](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) para discutir esses pontos com o pessoal.

Comment: Uma coisa que pode ajudar, é pedir ao autor da pergunta mais detalhes, para ajudar a cercar o problema (por exemplo, sugerir que ele poste o código do formulário de envio, e/ou as ultimas linhas do log de erros do PHP por exemplo), o que evita uma série de respostas que no fim pode nem ter ligação com o problema real do autor.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.